# Cannot add/modify entity in DB using attach/entry due to optimistic concurrency error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

In the following function (MVC action):

```
    // POST: api/Day
    public void Post(int bed, DateTime date, float operatingTime)
    {
        Day currentDay = new Day()
        {
            Date = date,
            BedId = bed,
            OperatingTime = operatingTime
        };

        db.Entry(currentDay).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The `Day` class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Day
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public float OperatingTime { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int BedId { get; set; }

    public virtual Bed Bed { get; set; }
}
```

In the action, the particular `Day` may or may not already exist. I intend for a new `Day` to be created if it doesn't exist or an existing one be updated. The `Day` table has `Date` and `BedId` as a composite primary key.

I also tried "attaching" the entity first.

Am I mistaken in assuming that my code will create a new entry if one with a matching (composite) key doesn't exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic will not create a new entry if one is not found. `EntityState.Modified` will create an `UPDATE` statement. If you want to insert if not found, then you'll need to query the db first. I don't like the idea of doing an insert OR an update inside a method called `Post`, but if you prefer that, you could try something like:

```
// POST: api/Day
public void Post(int bed, DateTime date, float operatingTime)
{
    Day currentDay = new Day()
    {
        Date = date,
        BedId = bed,
        OperatingTime = operatingTime
    };

    var dayExists = db.Day.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Date == date && d.BedId == bed);

    if (dayExists != null) 
    {
        // you have a record, so update it
        db.Entry(currentDay).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else 
    {
        // no record found, insert one
        db.Entry(currentDay).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```